# Illustrator: Should I use the biggest possible artboard for accuracy?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working on a project with another person via email and dropbox.   The final printed material will be 8 1/2 by 5 1/2 inches.  My approach is to see an artboard in the final printed dimensions while I work.   He was doing his work on much bigger artboard. I guess he believes that with a bigger artboard you can place things more accurately. I don't think he is correct on this.  I have turned off "Snap to Pixel" and turned off every other snap I could find.  I should be able to place anything as accurately as he can because this is a vector based program.  Am I wrong?   He apparently started with Photoshop and maybe be keeping some habits from that history.

Comment: Technically it does not matter since illusttator is using double floats and those get less accurate the further you move from the center of the origin but really how many digits of accuracy do you really need (a double is about 16 digits of numbers). As long as you dont trigger the large document mode i dont se any issue. But your friend may be right as far as historical illustrator goes, not a issue today.

Comment: Just so you ubderstand a double float can resolve 0.1 picometers if we allow 3 digits for edit rounding in a 1 meter wide document. To get how small this is its about 600 times smaller than a helium atom

Comment: FYI... Beyond any app abilities **eyesight** matters. The better your eyesight the less you need to rely on zoom... and for really bad eyesight 1600% may not be enough unless the objects themselves are larger.